# Faster to lock List<T> during iteration or to clone

Tags: c#, locking, gdi+

I currently have a program that intercepts some packets, does some modification/adding classes to lists based on the information and sends it on.

What I am currently doing is when I add an item I lock the list I'm adding to whilst I add it. However I have a PictureBox which draws information from the lists every 50ms or so. Currently the way I do it looks something like this:

```
Graphics g = e.Graphics;

lock (Core.Collections.SpaceStations)
{
    foreach (Classes.Station station in Core.Collections.SpaceStations)
    {
        Image img;
        switch (station.Company)
        {
            case 1:
                img = Prog.Properties.Resources.mmo_station;
                break;
            case 2:
                img = Prog.Properties.Resources.eic_station;
                break;
            case 3:
                img = Prog.Properties.Resources.vru_station;
                break;
            default:
                img = new Bitmap(50, 50);
                break;
        }
        g.DrawImage(img, (float)((station.Position.x - 750) / Core.CurrentMap.ByX), (float)((station.Position.y - 750) / Core.CurrentMap.ByY), 35, 35);
    }
}
```

As you can see, it locks for the entire length of the iteration which causes my packet handler to block until it finishes painting and can cause lag for both the server and client (because I lock before adding or removing items in the packet handler). My question is would it be quicker to copy all the items from the List into a temporary list inside the lock and then draw them all outside the lock from the temp list? Mainly my question is, is it faster to iterate through a list or to copy a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think copying the list is better option here.

It will defiantly improve the performance but would be memory intensive, which can be handled to an extend by properly disposing the list after drawing.

```
Station[] stations = Core.Collections.SpaceStations.ToArray();
```

Comment: Alright, the toarray is interesting. Does it have performance benefits over `List<Station> tempStation = new List<Station>(); tempStation.AddRange(Core.Collections.SpaceStations);`

Comment: As you are only reading from the list and not adding anything therefore you don't need the 'List<Station>'.

Comment: Alright, yeah that makes sense. So it does have performance benefits? Also, how would you "Dispose of it properly"?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your own list which allows you to add items while iterating ( read-only ) through the list. Only when you are deleting items you need to lock the list to prevent from iterating though it.

Of course your iterating thread doesn't knows new items at the point when iterating through it.

Benefits:

- Avoids copying while the list's capacity isn't changing, if it changes the readers still could finish reading. If it changes you still need to lock the list while copying the list items to a new array.
- Allows multiple threads to iterate through
- Allows adding items to list while iterating

*Disclaimer: This is very conceptual, never testet it*

Comment: Sounds interesting, I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: @jduncanator Give me feedback if it works :-) *Added more information about adding items*